# MySQL check if value exists in two tables in the same query

Tags: mysql

How does one write a QUERY (*if possible*) that searches for data/information in two tables at the same time?

Search FOR "value" IN *table1* and *table2* WHERE *argument*

Comment: Can yo be a little more specific? Maybe show some sample data for both tables and where you want to check for value and also your expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) (or `UNION ALL` if you want to preserve duplicate results).

For example:

```
select col1,col2 from table1 where col1 = 1
union
select col1,col2 from table2 where col1 = 1
```

Comment: An union would return values even if the value is found only in one of the tables

Comment: @slaakso That is what I want to happen in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

To search if a value exists in both tables you will use a join:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id
where t1.id in (1,2,3)
```